# Difference between these two array statements in java

Tags: java

> what is the difference between these 2 array staments in java. In Statement 1 we dont use ***new*** keyword so my question is there object is created or not.

**Statement 1:**   int[] arr = {10,20,30};

**Statement 2:**   int[] arr = new int[]{10,20,30};

Answer (score 1):

Both are the same, just a different way of writing:

1. In the first statement, the type is derived by the compiler in the array creation from the types / the declaration of arr.
2. In the second statement you have an explicit declaration of the instance. It contains more overhead.